# remove a Black shade in objects in 3ds max

Tags: 3ds-max

[image]

remove a Black shade in objects in 3ds max

Comment: 3D questions are no longer in the scope of this site.  There is a proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics) for a 3DSE, so go over and commit to it!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the word "Realistic" in your viewport and change it to "Shaded".

Answer (score 0):

You could right click on the object and set its properties to not cast shadows.

If this option is locked, you can change it by the layer its on or by changing it to "by object only"

Answer (score 0):

### **Method 1**

Click the Word `Realistic` in the top left of your Viewport.
Goto `Lighting and Shadows`
Deselect `Shadows`.

---

### **Method 2**

Click the Word `Realistic` in the top left of your Viewport.
Click `Shaded`